# Trying to run a simple example of Java NIO SSL to load the contents of https://www.amazon.com but getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https

Trying everyting but it does not work :(

The complete code and example can be found here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/java-nio-ssl-example/

Also you can download the full source (it is only 3 classes) by clicking here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/NioSSLExample.zip

Thanks for any help!

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class NioSSLExample
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("www.amazon.com", 443);
      Selector selector = Selector.open();
      SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
      channel.connect(address);
      channel.configureBlocking(false);
      int ops = SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ;

      SelectionKey key =  channel.register(selector, ops);

      // create the worker threads
      final Executor ioWorker = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      final Executor taskWorkers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

      // create the SSLEngine
      final SSLEngine engine = SSLContext.getDefault().createSSLEngine();
      engine.setUseClientMode(true);
      engine.beginHandshake();
      final int ioBufferSize = 32 * 1024;
      final NioSSLProvider ssl = new NioSSLProvider(key, engine, ioBufferSize, ioWorker, taskWorkers)
      {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Exception ex)
         {
            System.out.println("handshake failure");
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }

         @Override
         public void onSuccess()
         {
            System.out.println("handshake success");
            SSLSession session = engine.getSession();
            try
            {
               System.out.println("local principal: " + session.getLocalPrincipal());
               System.out.println("remote principal: " + session.getPeerPrincipal());
               System.out.println("cipher: " + session.getCipherSuite());
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
               exc.printStackTrace();
            }

            //HTTP request
            StringBuilder http = new StringBuilder();
            http.append("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            http.append("Connection: close\r\n");
            http.append("\r\n");
            byte[] data = http.toString().getBytes();
            ByteBuffer send = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            this.sendAsync(send);
         }

         @Override
         public void onInput(ByteBuffer decrypted)
         {
            // HTTP response
            byte[] dst = new byte[decrypted.remaining()];
            decrypted.get(dst);
            String response = new String(dst);
            System.out.print(response);
            System.out.flush();
         }

         @Override
         public void onClosed()
         {
            System.out.println("ssl session closed");
         }
      };

      // NIO selector
      while (true)
      {
         key.selector().select();
         Iterator keys = key.selector().selectedKeys().iterator();
         while (keys.hasNext())
         {
            keys.next();
            keys.remove();
            ssl.processInput();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        http.append("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        http.append("Connection: close\r\n");
        http.append("\r\n");
```

While this is in theory a correct HTTP/1.0 request in practice, most systems today require that a `Host` header is included. While this is mandatory only with HTTP/1.1 it is needed if an IP address hosts multiple domains:

```
        http.append("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        http.append("Host: www.amazon.com\r\n");
        http.append("\r\n");
```

Also note that the `Connection: close` is unnecessary since it is implicit with HTTP/1.0 (but not with HTTP/1.1).

Apart from that HTTP is way more complex than this simple request and even this one had its problems as you saw. If you need to implement it for yourself please study the standards instead of making assumptions of how servers react or looking only at a few examples.

Comment: You saved my life, thank you so much! That deserves the hammer story: https://medium.com/indian-thoughts/lesson-of-the-week-its-all-about-knowing-where-to-hit-ec08b5ced0c6